# Switch statement involving string and char

Tags: java

```
public class Example {

        public static void main (String [] args){
            String word = "apple";
            switch(word){ // by only changing this value
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            System.out.println("the word starts with a vowel"); 
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("the word doesn't start with a vowel");
    }
        }
    }
```

The error that I'm at is that

```
 char cannot be converted to a String
```

Am i supposed to be using the `charArray()` method if that's the case?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Fast Snail, i'm trying to get the code to compile and run the switch statement

Comment: @STJJ no i'm asking what your code should do ?

Comment: `if (word.matches("^[aeiou].*")) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just try and get the first element of the string instead of the whole word. The first element should be a `char`.

Like `word.charAt(0)`

Comment: Thanks man. So in this case if i input word.charAt(1), it basically will be reading from the point "pple" from the word "apple" and will return it as not starting with a vowel right?

Comment: Not quite, `word.charAt(1)` will return the 2nd element in this case 'p'. It only returns 1 `char`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want the switch case to be for the first letter of the word, not the whole word, so try this:

```
 switch(word.charAt(0)){ // by only changing this value
```